# How can I add C++11 support to Code::Blocks compiler?

Tags: c++11, codeblocks

I'm writing some code that requires to have C++11 support for my Code::Blocks  12.11. I am using default GNU GCC Compiler came with MingW. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 137):

1. Go to  `Toolbar -> Settings -> Compiler`
2. In the `Selected compiler` drop-down menu, make sure `GNU GCC Compiler` is selected
3. Below that, select the `compiler settings` tab and then the `compiler flags` tab underneath
4. In the list below, make sure the box for "`Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++  language standard [-std=c++11]`" is checked
5. Click `OK` to save

Answer (score 19):

The answer with screenshots (put the checkbox as in the second pic, then press OK):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 15):

A simple way is to write:

```
-std=c++11
```

in the *Other Options* section of the compiler flags.  You could do this on a per-project basis (*Project -> Build Options*), and/or set it as a default option in the *Settings -> Compilers* part.

Some projects may require `-std=gnu++11` which is like C++11 but has some GNU extensions enabled.

If using g++ 4.9, you can use `-std=c++14` or `-std=gnu++14`.

Comment: This is the only one that works using the latest version of CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `g++ -std=c++11 -o <output_file_name> <file_to_be_compiled>`

Comment: Noted. Although, from the context it should be self-evident.