# std::string' has no member named 'pop_back'

Tags: c++, sdl

Hello I get this error when I try to RUN Lazy foo's 32nd SDL2 tutorial code.

This is the code snippet

```
//lop off character
inputText.pop_back();
renderText = true;
```

Here is the declaration

```
        //The current input text.
        std::string inputText = "Some Text";
```

I'm using the most recent version of code::blocks 13.12. The function pop_back is highlighted in green as well. What is the issue? I have not modified his code in any way. You would think it would work out of the box since he recommended code::blocks

Comment: Code::blocks is an IDE, not a compiler.  Check the version of the compiler (more than likely, gcc) that is being used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add C++11 support to Code::Blocks compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler)

Answer (score 4):

This function is available starting from C++11:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/pop_back/

so your compiler must support it, you should check on this IDE forums for any info related to this issue, I have found one thread for you:

http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=18830.0

Comment: So does code::blocks not use c++11 ? What is going on here? Is there something I must configure?

Comment: with g++ you enable C++11 features with -std=c++11

Comment: The comment from @marcinj should be included in the answer, it works straight away. (I'm doing the same tutorials as the OP, and had the same issue)

Answer (score 0):

For Code::Blocks 17 tick the box in "Global compiler settings" or "Project build options" that says "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]". Also worth double checking that your compiler supports C++11.

[image: Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]]