# Integer to string in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I have problem with converting integer to string in C++ using CodeBlocks and GCC Compiler. I tried with this but it eject error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int clicks = 0;
    string code = to_string(clicks); //error: "to_string" was not declared in this scope
}
```

And also i tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()

{
    int clicks = 0;
    std::string code = std::to_string(clicks); // error: "to_string" is not memeber of "std"

}
```

Is there any solution? Pls help

Comment: You have to compile with C++11 enabled (GCC flag: `-std=c++11`), but I don't know how you can set that in CodeBlocks.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Not portable, but there are some portable alternatives that use `sprintf()` listed on that website.

Comment: Check [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `stringstream` like so:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << clicks;
std:string code = ss.str();
```

Include `sstream`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have support for C++11. How I figured that out? I checked the ref [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) and saw the C++11 icon.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler) on how to do this.

It pretty much says to follow these steps:

1. Go to Toolbar -> Settings -> Compiler
2. In the "Selected compiler" drop-down menu, make sure "GNU GCC
   Compiler" is selected
3. Below that, select the "compiler settings" tab and then the
   "compiler flags" tab underneath
4. In the list below, make sure the box for "Have g++ follow the C++11
   ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]" is checked
5. Click OK to save