# (C++) tried to include chrono, -std=c++0x not recognized

Tags: c++11

I'm using windows 7.
I am asked to use chrono to check function evaluation time. My instructor told me to compile with g++  -std=c++0x x.cpp

How could I do it in Codeblocks?

My friend uses/marks this flag in compiler settings: "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]. I did not have it so I manually created it then build and it gave this error:

unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

When I choose "Have g++ follow the coming C++0x ISO language standard -std=c++0x" , again it says:

unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"

I downloaded the same setup as my friend. And it gives same errors in Dev C++

What should I do?

I'm using GNU GCC Compiler
my friend also uses this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add C++11 support to code::blocks compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler)

Comment: You haven't mentioned your GCC version, which is critical in this question.

Comment: it is GNU GCC Compiler
my friend also uses this

Comment: and it is not a duplicate

Comment: Do mention the VERSION of the compiler. Type in `gcc --version`.

Comment: GCC supports `-std=c++0x` starting with version 4.3 and `-std=c++11` starting with version 4.7, so as @E_net4 mentions you should determine what version of GCC you're using.

Comment: I'm trying to find how could I type in gcc --version on codeblocks in windows

Comment: With GCC properly installed, the standard command line should suffice (cmd).

Comment: Are you talking about windows' standard cmd? And how?

Comment: Where did you get Code::Blocks from?  The current download page here: http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26 indicates that GCC 4.7.1 or later should be included for any of the Windows downloads.  Try using one of those downloads if you got Code::Blocks somewhere else.