# codeblocks shows error: This file requires support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks, gnu

I want to use poisson_distribution template in my C++ code (included in random header), but cant find a way to compile it without error

My codeblocks shows an error

> This file requires compiler and library support for the \
>   ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
>   enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

I remember while installing codeblocks I installed only gnu c/c++ compiler. Can anyone explain me how to update my compiler to standard `ISO C++ 2011` standard or suggest an alternative.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The compiler options in the settings page include a switch for C++11.

Comment: Settings->Compiler->Compiler Flags ->Check:"Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to update the compiler. You just need to set it to C++11 mode.

[How can I add C++11 support to Code::Blocks compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

A simple option would be to write

```
-std=c++11
```

As part of the other compiler options flags or directly in your Makefile.

Note that some projects may require `-std=gnu++11` which is like C++11 but has some GNU extensions enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Compiler >
select the checkbox:
'Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard'