# using stoi problems(c++11)

Tags: c++11, mingw, codeblocks

- I'm using code::blocks IDE. I want to use stoi in my code but always

---

I take this error :

---

'stoi' was not declared in this scope I'm using
   gnu gcc compiler 4.8.1 and i'm using c++11 and I have 64bit computer.

---

I've checked on the internet and I've made the changes specified on this page:
http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string

---

I don't wonna use atoi!
**but i can't use stoi yet!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

int main()
{ 
   int temp; 
   string test = "123hello"; 
   temp = stoi(test); 
   cout << temp; 
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe read [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Did you `#include <string>` ?

Comment: yes of course! I've included string and used namespace std

Comment: @juanchopanza I've did it right!

Comment: @Ahmadreza That is very unlikely, otherwise it would have worked. In any case, you have shown no evidence that you "did it right".

Comment: can you paste some code...

Comment: I just initialized a string and used stoi and put the returned value in a variable!

Comment: @Nick : #include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int temp;
    string test = "123hello";
    temp = stoi(test);
    cout << temp;
    return 0;
}

Comment: are you sure #include<string> is same as #include<string.h>? also try std::stoi() instead of stoi()

Comment: I've tested it ! the same error ! :((

Comment: You code works fine on Ubuntu with g++ 4.8.4 so it must be a minGW/g++ 4.8.1  issue.

Comment: does the answer here help: [how can i add c++11 support to code::blocks compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24398366/539810)

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I've done this works!