# STL linked list issues

Tags: c++

My logic seems to be wrong in my code. The rule states that for every "e" at the end of a 3 or more letter word, the "e" must be removed. So for example "remove" would be changed to "remov" or another example is "ease" would be changed to "eas". I tried using myList.size -1 but i got a compilation error. Can somebody please help?

I will mark down the error spot for convenience.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void printList(const list<char> &myList);
void fillList(list<char> &myList);
void change(list <char> &myList);

void printList(const list<char> &myList)
{
    list<char>::const_iterator itr;
    for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
    {
        cout <<*itr;
    }
    cout << '\n' << endl;
}

void fillList(list<char> &myList)
{
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    string print;
    while(file >> print)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<=print.length(); i++)
        {
            myList.push_back(print[i]);
        }
        myList.push_back(' ');
    }
}

void change(list <char> &myList)
{
    list<char>::iterator itr;

    //rules are as follows

    //change w with v
    for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
    {
        if (*itr == 'w')
        {
            *itr = 'v';
        }

    }

    //remove e at the end of a 3+ letter word
    //PROBLEM HERE
    for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
    {
        std::list<char>::iterator itr2 = myList.size() - 1;
        if(myList.size() > 3 && itr2 == 'e')
        {
            myList.erase(itr2);
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    list<char> myList;
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    const string print;
    fillList(myList);
    printList(myList);
    change(myList);
    printList(myList);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to convert an integer to an iterator? It seems nonsense.

Comment: @MikeCAT you got any suggestions? I know what I need to do, but I am unsure how to get there.

Comment: `myList.erase(*itr2);` also looks weird because `std::list::erase()` will take a iterator as parameter, not `char`.

Comment: @MikeCAT oh wait it is suppose to be myList.erase(itr). I'll edit that

Comment: Are you trying to reverse iterate through the list?

Comment: @tadman I am trying to get the last character in the word and check if it is an "e". If the character is a "e", I want to remove it.

Comment: So you do need a reverse iterator since you're starting at the end.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i<=print.length(); i++)` be careful for [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Comment: could pop_back() work? I can't really think now

Comment: @MikeCAT Yeah I was thinking about that I have looked everywhere but i haven't found a fix for it. You got any suggestions?

Comment: Has anyone got any suggestions to fix this code please? I am soo confused now

Answer (score 2):

You are using the following logic to remove `e`s.

```
for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
{
    std::list<char>::iterator itr2 = myList.size() - 1;
    if(myList.size() > 3 && itr2 == 'e')
    {
        myList.erase(itr2);
    }
}
```

The line

```
    std::list<char>::iterator itr2 = myList.size() - 1;
```

leads to compiler error since the RHS of the assignment operator is of type `size_t`. You cannot use a `size_t` to initialize an object of type `std::list<char>::iterator`.

More importantly, you don't seem to have thought through the logic clearly.

To remove an item from the list, it has to meet three criteria.

1. The item is `e`.
2. The item is the last letter of a word.
3. The word must be of length 3 or greater.

The first check is simple.

```
if ( *itr == 'e' )
```

The second check is a little more complex.

```
auto next = std::next(itr);
if ( *next == '\0' )
```

The third check is a little bit more complex than either of the first two. Since your list has embedded null characters followed by a space character before the next word starts, you'll need to keep a counter for word length and reset it when you see a space character.

Here's a block of code that implements the above logic:

```
int wordLength = 1;

// Don't use ++iter in the last clause of the for statement.
// iter is incremented only when the item is not removed.
// It is updated differently when the item is removed.

for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); )
{
   if ( needToRemove(itr, wordLength) )
   {
      // Remove the item.          
      itr = myList.erase(itr);
   }
   else
   {
      ++itr;
      ++wordLength;
   }
   if ( *itr == ' ' )
   {
      // Reset word length. The next character is
      // going to be the start of the next word.
      wordLength = 0;
   }
}
```

where `needToRemove` is defined as:

```
bool needToRemove(list<char>::iterator itr,
                  int wordLength) 
{
   if ( *itr != 'e' || wordLength < 3)
   {
      return false;
   }

   auto next = std::next(itr);
   return (*next == '\0');
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu Can you please explain the second check? 
That one
auto next = std::next(itr);
if ( *next == '\0' )

Comment: @TheByteMonster, `std::next(itr)` returns an iterator that points to the next item of the list. If the next item is not the null character, then the `e` is not the last character of a word.

Comment: I think you should be checking for ' ' as well as '\0' as each line (and the indiviual words) are space separated.

Comment: @R Sahu I am getting an error on the line where 
    auto next = std::next(itr);
    return (*next == '\0');
It is telling me next isn't declared in the scope and has no type.
While I've got your attention what is the keyword auto mean?

Comment: @TheByteMonster, make sure you use `#include <algorithm>` and you are compiler is enabled for C++11 features.

Comment: @R Sahu Sorry but i am still getting thrown an error,even after including the algorithm library.  I am using codeblocks with the mingW compiler

Comment: @TheByteMonster, can't help you there. It works for me using g++ 4.8.4 on a Linux desktop.

Comment: @RSahu so are you saying changing my compiler to g++ would work?

Comment: @TheByteMonster, you'll have to figure out how to enable C++11 features in CodeBlocks. This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler

Comment: @RSahu Ahh ok thank you soo much! I managed to get the code running. I never even knew that C++ uses different compilers. I come from a java and vb background

Comment: @TheDark, the newlines are skipped when getting input since the OP uses `file >> print` to read the input.