# Error: does not name a type (using auto)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am studying auto with the c++ primer 5th edition. They gave me examples such as:

```
auto item = val1 + val2;
```

From what I understand auto tells you what type forms from the expression you make. So I did my own:

```
int test1 = 69, test2 = 72;
auto test3 = test1 + test2;
```

but i got the error: " 'test3' does not name a type"

What does this mean? I though test3 will become the same type as test1,test2 which is int.

Comment: What compiler / options are you using to compile, it sounds like you're compiling without C++11 support.

Comment: @kfsone im using codeblocks with the builtin mingw. C++11 is enabled by default. EDIT: I tried using the command -std=c++11, same result

Comment: Damn bugs, it works in http://cpp.sh/35avt but not with code::blocks

Comment: In your deleted answer you say you went to "projects > set project arguments" but there is no such place. Maybe you misread "Projects > Set *program* arguments", which means the arguments passed to *your executable* when you are running it after having successfully compiled.

Comment: @M.M dam... your right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run the example without `--std=c++11`, it fails with the same error message.

Try to configure codeblocks again like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler) suggests.

Or you can run the code by hand like `g++ --std=c++11 code.cc`.

To see if C++11 is enabled, you can type more C++11 code, like just declaring nested vector `vector<vector<int>> vv;` to see if it deals `>>` well.

---

1. [How can I add C++11 support to Code::Blocks compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out was about to answer my own question but thanks for the answer anyways. What I did was go to project->set project arguments and add -std=c++11 BUT IT DID NOT WORK. So i googled it and got it running now, but thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

if you using code blocks go to settings in the up bar click on compiler...
then mark "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard" option.
else if U use another programme then you have to search how to activite c++11 option in the programme