# What is difference between "long int a=2" and "int a=2L"?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between `unsigned int a=2` and `int a=2U`

Also,

`sizeof(a)` operator gives the same value for `int a=2` and `int a=2L` , why? Shouldn't the size be doubled.

UPDATE:
Thanks all for the answers.
here is the summery:

1. `long int` or `int` are types with which variable is declared. `2` or `2L` is the value with which variable is initialised.
2. Size of the variable is declared by type instead of its initialisation, so both will have same size

Comment: `long char` doesn't exist.

Comment: Don't you get a compiler warning "assigning long to int" at `int a=2L;`?

Comment: No , I don't get any error or warning(i am using code blocks)

Comment: @AvinashKumarShudhanshu He didn't ask about _errors_. He was asking about _warnings_.

Comment: One is long, the other is an `int`. Surely this is obvious? Unclear why you think `int` should have two different sizes, or why you are asking about nonexistent types.

Comment: @interjay then why don't i get error for `char c=L'a'`

Comment: The size of variable is set by its type, not by the value you store in it.

Comment: Additional reading on: [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: @EJP I think long is a modifier and int is the data type. Am I wrong?

Comment: Note that `sizeof(long)` isn't necessary greater than `sizeof(int)` in the first place. When I was starting out, the two were both 32 bits with my implementation.

Comment: `long` is a type all by itself. [It can also be written `long int`, or `signed long int`, or even `int long signed`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726423/is-long-long-long-long-int-long-int-long-int-long-long?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @AvinashKumarShudhanshu Even if it was, which it isn't, why are you assuming it has no effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, all variables are declared with type. C++ forces<sup>1</sup> you to specify the type explicitly, but doesn't force you to initialize the variable at all.

```
long int a = 2;
long int b = 2L;
long int c;
```

This code makes 3 variables of the same type `long int`.

```
int a = 2;
int b = 2L;
int c;
```

This code makes 3 variables of the same type `int`.

The idea of *type* is roughly "the set of all values the variable can take". It doesn't (and cannot) depend on the initial value of the variable - whether it's `2` or `2L` or anything else.

So, if you have two variables of different type but same value

```
int a = 2L;
long int b = 2;
```

The difference between them is what they can do *further in the code*. For example:

```
a += 2147483647; // most likely, overflow
b += 2147483647; // probably calculates correctly
```

The type of the variable won't change from the point it's defined onwards.

Another example:

```
int x = 2.5;
```

Here the type of `x` is `int`, and it's initialized to 2. Even though the initializer has a different type, C++ regards the declaration type of `x` "more important".

---

<sup>1</sup> BTW C++ has support for "type inference"; you can use it if you want the type of the initializer to be important:

```
auto a = 2L; // "a" has type "long int"
auto b = 2; // "b" has type "int"
```

Comment: Got it, 
thing is, `int a=2L` , though a is initialized with value '2' which is of long int type, a is still int type.
The variable of one type can be initialized with a value of another type

Comment: I tried:  `auto a = 2L;`  It gives the error: **'a' does not name a type** why?

Comment: Maybe you're using an old compiler. This syntax of using `auto` is relatively new (C++11, 5 years old now). See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10363646/509868) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37582094/509868) for hints on how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

> What is difference between "long int a=2" and "int a=2L"?

The former defines a variable `a` as having type `long int` initialised from the value `2`, the latter defines it as having type `int` initialised from the value `2L`. The initialiser is implicitly converted to the type of the variable, and does not affect the type of the variable.

> Or what is the difference between `long char c='a'` and `char c=L'a'`

The former defines a variable `c` as having type `long char` initialised from the value `'a'`, the latter defines it as having type `char` initialised from the value `L'a'`. Since the type `long char` doesn't exist, the former is an error. The type of `L'a'` is called `wchar_t`, not `long char`, and in the latter case is again converted to the type of the variable.

> or what is the difference between `unsigned int a=2` and `int a=2U`

The former defines a variable `a` as having type `unsigned int` initialised from the value `2`, the latter defines it as having type `int` initialised from the value `2U`. Yet again, the initialiser does not affect the type of the variable.

> Also,
>
> `sizeof(a)` operator gives the same value for `int a=2` and `int a=2L` , why? Shouldn't the size be doubled.

Since they both define `a` as type `int`, `sizeof(a)` should give `sizeof(int)` for both.

Comment: help me, exactly that is where I am confused **The initialiser is implicitly converted to the type of the variable, and does not affect the type of the variable.** if it does not effect, then what is its use.
and
as memory is allocated according to the type of variable then how can 2L(int long type) accommodate inside the memory block which has size of int only,

Comment: @AvinashKumarShudhanshu `int a=2L;` does exactly the same thing as `int a=2;`. It's the value that is being converted, not the bytes that make up that value. Converting `2L` to type `int` simply produces `2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a1=2;      //a1=2
    int a2=2L;     //a2=2
    int a3=2.5673; //a3=2
    int a4='A';    //a4=65
    return 0;
}
```

Here, even though the value of `a3` and `a4` is `float` and `char` respectively, the value will be transformed to int as `a3` and `a4` is declared as an `int`. In the same way, the value of `a2` will be transformed into `int` even though the value was set as 2L.
The variable doesn't depend on the value, rather on type declaration. `int` a will always be an integer, no matter what's it's value is.