# std::future example not working with CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, c++11, std, codeblocks

I have just installed CodeBlocks 16.01 on Windows 7 and set it up to use C++ 11 support as described in the former answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler).  I then try to run the sample code given [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) and get the following error messages when I try to compile.

```
 ||=== Build: Debug in MyProgram (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
 C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|8|error: variable 'std::packaged_task<int()> task' has initializer but incomplete type|
 C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|9|error: variable 'std::future<int> f1' has initializer but incomplete type|
 C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|10|error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'|
 C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|13|error: variable 'std::future<int> f2' has initializer but incomplete type|
 C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|13|error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::future<int>'|
 c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\future|114|error: declaration of 'class std::future<int>'|
 C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|16|error: aggregate 'std::promise<int> p' has incomplete type and cannot be defined|
 C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|17|error: variable 'std::future<int> f3' has initializer but incomplete type|
 C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|18|error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'|
 c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\future|172|error: 'std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = main()::<lambda()>; _Args = {}; typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type = int]', declared using local type 'main()::<lambda()>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]|
 ||=== Build failed: 10 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

EDIT:

The build log is as follows.

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g -std=c++11  -c     C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp:8:35: error: variable 'std::packaged_task<int()> task' has initializer but incomplete type
 std::packaged_task<int()> task([](){ return 7; }); // wrap the function
```

The output is

```
 ||=== Build: Debug in MyProgram (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|8|error: variable 'std::packaged_task<int()> task' has initializer but incomplete type|
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|9|error: variable 'std::future<int> f1' has initializer but incomplete type|
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|10|error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'|
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|13|error: variable 'std::future<int> f2' has initializer but incomplete type|
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|13|error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::future<int>'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\future|114|error: declaration of 'class std::future<int>'|
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|16|error: aggregate 'std::promise<int> p' has incomplete type and cannot be defined|
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|17|error: variable 'std::future<int> f3' has initializer but incomplete type|
C:\codeBlocksProjects\MyProgram\main.cpp|18|error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\future|172|error: 'std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = main()::<lambda()>; _Args = {}; typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type = int]', declared using local type 'main()::<lambda()>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build failed: 10 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Which MinGW version do you use?

Comment: check the console output during build. I bet there's no -std=c++11 on the command line

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot.  Version 5

Comment: @ Richard Hodges.  I was lacking that in the command line and corrected it but still get much the same error messages.  I have documented my changes, and results, in my edited question.  Thanks,

Comment: Can't reproduce: C::B 16.01, Windows 7, TDM-GCC-32/64 or mingw-w64

Comment: I'm using mingw32-g++.exe.  Could that be the problem?  Thanks,

Comment: I replaced the 32-bit compiler with the 64-bit version (g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11  -c C:\codeBlocksProjects\myProgram\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o) but still the same problems.  Thanks,

Comment: Sorry.  "g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g -std=c++11  -c C:\codeBlocksProjects\myProgram\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o".  Still the same results.