# create multiple text files inside a loop

Tags: c++, file

I want to create some text file in C++. For example: I will run a loop from 1 to 5 and create the following files:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
```

is it possible? I have made a sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

main()
{
   FILE *fp;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        //fp=fopen("%d.txt","r",i); //what will go here??

 }
}
```

I am confused about what I will write inside the loop. how can I create those files?

Comment: Create the file name separately in a `std::string` variable ans use the `c_str()` to pass it to `fopen()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
char i;
char fileName[] = "0.txt";
for(i='1';i<='5';i++)
{
   fileName[0]=i;
   fp=fopen(fileName,"r"); //what will go here??
   //...
}
```

You can use `sprintf` if this is too simple for your case;

---

Since you tag `c++`, I think `fstream` `string` is the thing to use.

A simple c++ example

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   string base(".txt");
   for(int i=1;i<=5;++i){
      ofstream(to_string(i)+base);// to_string() need c++11
   }
}
```

---

If you still don't have `to_string` (you don't have `c++11` or your compiler just don't have this) you can use this simple version for now. (better put this in your own `namespace`)

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string to_string(int i){
   std::stringstream s;
   s << i;
   return s.str();
}
```

Comment: This will not behave as asked if i > '9' (since the 1 to 5 part is an example)

Comment: than use `sprintf` or just use `c++` things, I'm adding them to my answer

Comment: I am getting an error saying to_string was not declatred in this scope @apple apple

Comment: @AAA What compiler are you using and in which standard are you compiling? `to_string()` is defined in `<string>`, but since C++11.

Comment: I am using Code Blocks version  13.12 @Bob__

Comment: @AAA It's a bit old. Have you tried to add the option `-std=c++11` to the compiler options?

Comment: I am very new to this. can you please describe the process of adding it? @Bob__

Comment: @AAA look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler).

Comment: @AAA you can use `to_string` in updated answer, but I would suggest update your compiler.

Comment: If I want to write "hello" in each file inside the loop. what I will have to do? @apple apple

Comment: @AAA I see other of your question, and I think you need to learn the basic of `c++` before asking similar question multiple times, and if you really understand any of your question's answer, you will not have these duplicate question.

Comment: @AAA to answer your question, `ofstream file("name"); file<<"hello";`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to compose the file name before passing it to the `std::ofstream` constructor as a `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "How many files do you want to create? ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << "How many digits do you want to display? ";
    int n_digits;
    std::cin >> n_digits;   // i.e. zeroes == 3  ->  001.txt

    std::cout << "Enter a common prefix for all the files: ";
    std::string prefix;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::getline(std::cin, prefix);  // i.e. prefix == "file"  -> file001.txt

    std::string ext(".txt");
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i )
    {   // use a stringstream to create a file names like: prefix001.txt
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << prefix << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(n_digits) << i << ext;

        // open the file. If not c++11 use  ss.str().c_str()  instead
        std::ofstream file( ss.str() );
        if ( !file )
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: failed to create file " << ss.str() << '\n';
            break;
        }

        // write something to the newly created file
        file << "This is file: " << ss.str() << "\n\nHello!\n";
        if ( !file )
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: failed to write to file " << ss.str() << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{

    std::ofstream out; // you must call out.close() inside loop to be able to open another file for writting otherwise you'll get only the first one "a.txt"
    std::string sFileName;

    for(char c('a'); c < 'f'; c++)
    {
        sFileName =  c;
        sFileName += ".txt";
        out.open(sFileName.c_str(), std::ios::out);
    //  std::ofstream out(sFileName.c_str(), std::ios::out); // here you are not obliged to call out.close() because the first out is not the very second and so on...
        out.close(); // very important if you use the same ofstream to open another file
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*** to be able to use one ostream object in opening many files you must close the precedent file to be able to open the next otherwise it fails trying  creating the next one.