# Having Trouble in Using is_sorted in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, t;
    vector <int> v;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--) {
        scanf("%d", &j);
        v.push_back(j);
    }

    if(is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end()))
        printf("Sorted\n");
    else
        printf("Unsorted\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my C++ code to check whether a vector is sorted or not. But my IDE (Code Blocks) doesn't compile it and gives the message "is_sorted was not declared in this scope". What's wrong with this code?

Comment: a) CodeBlocks is not a compiler b) enable C++11

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the compile flag.

```
[root@router ~]# cat t.cpp 
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int i, j, t;
        vector <int> v;
        scanf("%d", &t);

        while(t--) {
                scanf("%d", &j);
                v.push_back(j);
        }

        if(is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end()))
                printf("Sorted\n");
        else
                printf("Unsorted\n");

        return 0;
}
[root@router ~]# g++ -o t t.cpp -std=c++11
```

Here is the [std::is_sorted reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted).

Comment: @Najat It's `-std=c++11` (only one hyphen).