# I am using Codeblocks 16.01 compiler and I am getting an error when i try to use unordered_set in my code

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-set

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_set>
using namespace std;
unordered_set<int> s;
int main()
{
  int n, k, val;
  cin >> n >> k;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin >> val;
    s.insert(val);
  }
  int ans = 0;
  for (unordered_set<int>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
    if (s.find(*it + k) != s.end()) ans++;
  cout << ans << endl;
  return 0;}
```

It just says

> error: 'unordered_set' does not name a type

Am I missing anything? or is there some problem with the compiler?

Comment: Code::Blocks is not a compiler. Can you include your compiler and the corresponding flags? It [works for me](http://ideone.com/ojTLUm).

Comment: Did you turn on C++11?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks man! that solved my problem.