# Strings as File names

Tags: c++, codeblocks

If I set a string as a filename, it doesn't work and I have no idea why. (I'm using codeblocks and it seems to work on other IDEs)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string FileName="Test.txt";
   ofstream File;
   File.open(FileName);
}
```

This does not work,while this next one does:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   ofstream File;
   File.open("Test.txt");
}
```

Error message:

> no matching function for call to std::basic_ofstream::open(std::string&)

Can someone help a bit with this problem, I cannot understand why this error occurs.

Comment: Do you use the compiler switch -std=c++11?

Comment: Do you have a pre-C++03 compiler?

Comment: Confusion between C strings and C++ strings, try File.open(FileName.c_str());. Or use a more up to date compiler.

Comment: @molbdnilo the std::string overload is C++11, not C++03.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler

Comment: You probably don't have `c++11` so you cannot use `const std::string &` overload http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `ofstream File; File.open(FileName);` should be `ofstream File(FileName);`. There's no reason here for creating an empty file object and then opening it.

Answer (score 6):

Due to what should be considered a historical accident in the early era of C++ standardisation, C++ file streams originally didn't support `std::string` for filename parameters, only `char` pointers.

That's why something like `File.open(FileName)`, with `FileName` being a `std::string`, didn't work and had to written as `File.open(FileName.c_str())`.

`File.open("Test.txt")` always worked because of the usual array conversion rules which allow the `"Test.txt"` array to be treated like a pointer to its first element.

C++11 fixed the `File.open(FileName)` problem by adding [`std::string` overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open).

If your compiler doesn't support C++11, then perhaps you should get a newer one. Or perhaps it does support C++11 and you just have to turn on the support with a flag like `-std=c++11`.