# Write a function that returns a pointer to the maximum value using pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers

This is the problem that I'm trying to solve for class in C++.

> Write a function that returns a pointer to the maximum value of an array of floating-point data: `double* maximum(double* a, int size)`. If size is 0, return `nullptr`.

The issues I'm having are that:

1. The final output is not the correct location for the maximum value in the array.
2. An error that says: "cannot convert 'double**' to 'double*' in the initialization".
3. If I use `nullptr` at any point in this code, CodeBlocks gives me an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// return pointer to location from function
double * maximum(double* a, int size)
{
    double maxVal = a[0]; // this is the starting max value
    double* max_pos = &a; // points to the value in a[0]
    // initialis]ze both variables
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        if(a[i] > maxVal){
            maxVal = a[i];
            cout << max_pos << endl;
            max_pos = &a[i];
        }
    }
    // return address
    return max_pos;
}

int main()
{
    double myarr[5];
    int i = 0;
    int arrSize = 5;

    cout << "Input 5 floating point values for your array" << endl;

    for(i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){ // loop to input values

        cin >> myarr[i];

    }
    for(int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++){
        cout << "Location for " << myarr[j] << " = " << &myarr[j] << endl;
    }
    double* maxNum = maximum( myarr, arrSize);     
    cout << &maxNum << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I'm getting after finding `max_pos`:

[image]

Comment: `nullptr` does not appear to be defined, so why *wouldn't* you expect an error if you try to use it?

Comment: `double* max_pos = &a;` looks a little odd to me. It takes the address of a pointer and tries to assign it to a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: How do you know the address being printed is wrong?  How do you know what the *correct* address should be?

Comment: you're printing the address of the pointer in the last line `cout << &maxNum << end;` Just print the pointer itself `cout << maxNum << endl;`

Comment: @ScottHunter What do you mean? Also I didn't add it on this code cause I was trying to get it to run without it first. But I've gotten the error before in another program I've had to use it for.

Comment: &a doesn’t point to the value in a[0]; a does

Comment: `nullptr` is most likely missing because C++11 support has not been turned on. Give [How can I add C++11 support to Code::Blocks compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler) a read.

Comment: on main() - I have each value listed with its location to test the code and it doesn't come out right.

Comment: @user4581301 Are you saying I need to change `&a` to `a`?? And thanks a bunch for that link for helping me fix `nullptr` it worked on my other code.

Comment: No I wasn't, I wasn't suggesting any solution because I'm a jerk. That is the correct thing to do, though.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I haven't, I'm a super noob. I'm still learning my way around this complier I'm using.

Comment: @RicardoMartinez `{return std::max_element(a, a + size);}` -- Wow, that was simple.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed has a few mistakes in it:

1. [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is bad!
2. you are not following your instructions to return `nullptr` when `size` is 0.
3. you are trying to initialize `max_pos` (a `double*`) with `&a` (a `double**`), which is a compiler error.
4. you are passing `&maxNum` (a `double**`) to `std::cout`, printing the address of the `maxNum` variable itself, not the address that it is pointing to (the found array element).  You need to pass `maxNum` (a `double*`) if you want to print the *address* of the found element, or pass `*maxNum` (a `double`) if you want to print the *value* of the found element.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

// return pointer to location from function
double* maximum(double *a, int size)
{
    if (size == 0) return 0;

    // initialize both variables
    double* max_pos = a; // points to the value in a[0]
    double maxVal = *max_pos; // this is the starting max value
    std::cout << "max_pos = " << max_pos << " (" << maxVal << ")" << std::endl;

    for(int i = 1; i < size; ++i){
        if (a[i] > maxVal){
            max_pos = &a[i];
            maxVal = *max_pos;
            std::cout << "max_pos = " << max_pos << " (" << maxVal << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // return address
    return max_pos;
}

int main()
{
    const int arrSize = 5;
    double myarr[arrSize];

    std::cout << "Input " << arrSize << " floating point values for your array" << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) { // loop to input values
        std::cin >> myarr[i];
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < arrSize; ++j) {
        std::cout << "Location for " << myarr[j] << " = " << &myarr[j] << std::endl;
    }

    double* maxNum = maximum(myarr, arrSize);
    std::cout << "maxNum = " << maxNum << " (" << *maxNum << ")" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/pwc2D6)

And then, you can throw it all away and use STL algorithms instead, like  `std::max_element()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const int arrSize = 5;
    double myarr[arrSize];

    std::cout << "Input " << arrSize << " floating point values for your array" << std::endl;

    // loop to input values
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin), arrSize, myarr);

    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Location for " << myarr[i] << " = " << &myarr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    double *maxNum = std::max_element(myarr, myarr + arrSize);
    std::cout << "maxNum = " << maxNum << " (" << *maxNum << ")" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/Q2phQq)

Comment: Just curious, but why do you use STL algorithms instead? For every class that I've done, we've never been shown this.

Comment: @RicardoMartinez because C++ classes tend to not teach *real world* C++, they focus more on C-isms, algorithm theories for things that the STL employs (case in point - a manual implementation of `std::max_element()`), etc, while *real* programmers in *real world* situations do use the STL. It is standardized, safer, and saves time and effort.