# Segment fault by running virtual function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, virtual

Every time I run my code. The terminal says "Segment fault". (I'm new to c++ so maybe you could help me improving my code) I have a base class called "Animal" and a "Dog" and a "Cat" class. I wan't to run "doSmth". In the main I created Cat* and Dog* both Pointer. I use CodeBlocks and my Operating System is Ubuntu 16.04.

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

class Cat;
class Dog;

class Animal
{
    public:
        Animal();
        virtual ~Animal();

        virtual void doSmth();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif

#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H

class Cat : public Animal
{
    public:
        Cat();
        virtual ~Cat();

        void doSmth()
        {
            std::cout << "Miau" << std::endl;
        }

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif

#ifndef DOG_H
#define DOG_H

class Dog : public Animal
{
    public:
        Dog();
        virtual ~Dog();

        void doSmth()
        {enter code here
            std::cout << "Wuff" << std::endl;
        }

    protected:

    private:

};

#endif

int main()
{
    Dog* d;
    Cat* c;

    d->doSmth();
    c->doSmth();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialized `Dog* d;` or `Cat* c;`!

Comment: Not related to your segfault. Consider add `override` when you override a virtual function. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

Comment: Stripping away most of the cruft, I'm nearly certain what you're trying to do is [**this**](https://ideone.com/edVHGk). At least that is what it would seem.

Comment: Most compilers can catch this sort of error these days. Don't ignore the warnings. They often contain important information about how your program will screw up.

Comment: You don't need to dynamically allocate variables.  Use pointers only when necessary. (BTW, you never allocate memory for your critters, you only declare pointers that point *somewhere* or *anywhere* but not allocated memory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting a segmentation fault is because you have not allocated memory for either `d`, or `c`, and are trying to access uninitialized data. Change the two declaration lines to:

```
Dog* d = new Dog{};
Cat* c = new Cat{};
```

The `new` operator allocates memory for each of these two classes, although it isn't the only way to do so. Also as a recommendation, I would avoid using pointers here since you don't need them.

On a side note, when overriding virtual functions, one should use the `override` keyword. (In >C++11)

Comment: Just to add to this, since you mention you are new to C++: `override` will only work if your compiler supports C++11 *and* if you have enabled it when compiling. If you use Ubuntu 16.04, the default `g++` compiler should be fine for C++11, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler) to see how you can activate the C++11 option in CodeBlocks

Comment: It is unnecessary to initialise the pointers using operator `new`.   It IS necessary to initialise them so they point at valid objects that exist as long as needed.

Comment: @Peter my answer was only limited to the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create objects before you use them.

If you are not accessing either object through a pointer to base class, there is no point in having virtual methods.  So in this case, you may want your pointers to be `Animal *`.

Also, since you are now allocating memory for your objects, you should release it by using `delete[]`.

```
Animal *d = new Dog;
Animal *c = new Cat;

d->doSmth();
c->doSmth();

delete[] c;
delete[] d;
```

You will also have to implement `Dog::Dog()`, `Dog::~Dog()`, `Cat::Cat()`, `Cat::~Cat()`, `Animal::Animal()`, `Animal::~Animal()` and `Animal::doSmth()` if you didn't already.