# my codeblocks don't supports tuple. what can i do now?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>

using namespace std;



int main()
{

    tuple< int ,char,float>temp;

    temp = make_tuple( 10, 'a',  5.5);

    cout<<"the initial values of tuples are:";
    cout<<get<0>(temp) << " " <<get<1>(temp)<,endl;
}
```

> ```
> #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
> ```
>
> while i compile my code it shows this.

Comment: Go to Project|Build Options and enable C++11 support.

Comment: Is `<,endl` supposed to be `<<endl`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you activate the c++11:

[How can I add C++11 support to Code::Blocks compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler)

You have an error in your code because you used `<,` and its supposed to be `<<` otherwise it works fine for me on VS