# Which version of c++ does CodeBlocks use?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Recently I have tried to use some Advance c++ functions in CodeBlocks but all the time it throw errors like " according to c++ 98....... ".
If CodeBlocks uses an old version of c++ can I update it to c++11 or  c++14.
I am just a new learner and cordially requesting you to help if you know the answer.

Comment: I really advise you take out time to learn the very rudiments of the language. Try to learn about compilers, for instance. Codeblocks is an IDE that works with the help of a compiler. There are different types of compilers and each with different versions, depending on the C++ standard they support.

Comment: The answer could depend on what compiler is used. `Code::Blocks` is an IDE not a compiler.

Answer (score 4):

You can set compiler version and language standart in settings.
See this [How can I add C++11 support to Code::Blocks compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler)